# Write multiple data frames (list of df) to excel worksheets where df name == worksheet name

Tags: r

I'm trying to save multiple dataframes to multiple sheets of single workbook where sheet name is same as df name.

Let say we splitted following in list of df$`1` to df`10`, how can i save them to workbook with sheets named 1 to 10.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

data <- tibble( x = 1:10,
                y = runif(10,0.1,10),
                z = runif(10,0.1,10))

df <- split(data, data$x)

wb <- loadWorkbook("template.xlsx")
```

Here comes missing step, i tired to use purrr:map (pretty much inexpirienced with purrr, and R in general) but not sure how to feed it that df$`1` corresponds to sheet named 1.

```
map(df,function(x) x %>% 
      writeData(wb,.....)
```

```
saveWorkbook(wb, "finished_workbook.xlsx")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an external package, `mapply` can do what you want.
Note that the workbook `"template.xlsx"` must already exist.

```
library(openxlsx)

df <- split(data, data$x)

wb <- loadWorkbook("template.xlsx")
```

Now the tricky part. This function is called by `mapply` to write the several tables in the sheets named `"1"` to `"10"`.

The function `fun` assumes the sheets already exist but does not assume they are empty. It starts by seeing how many tables each sheet has and if any (`length(g) > 0`), removes them all. Only then it writes table `x`, with a call to `tryCatch` wrapped around `writeDataTable` in order to catch possible errors.
If there is an error, return it, if not, return the character string `"Ok"`.

```
fun <- function(s, x){
  g <- getTables(wb, sheet = s)
  if(length(g) > 0){
    sapply(g, function(.g) removeTable(wb, s, .g))
  }
  err <- tryCatch(writeDataTable(wb, s, x),
                  error = function(e) e)
  if(inherits(err, "error")) err else "Ok"
}

mapply(fun, names(df), df)
#   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
#"Ok" "Ok" "Ok" "Ok" "Ok" "Ok" "Ok" "Ok" "Ok" "Ok"

saveWorkbook(wb, "template.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Not at the PC at the moment, but will this work if sheets already exist in template? I'm aware that template workbook need to exist prior to loading. Thanks

Comment: @DonSpan No, it throws an error if the sheets already exist. This can be corrected. What do you want to do if the sheets already exist? Remove them (one by one) and write anew?

Comment: Maybe my first post wasn't clear enough and I aplogoize for that  by i need to write df to existing sheets that are alredy in template.xlsx.So df$`1` to sheet named 1, df$`2` to sheet named 2, and so on.

Comment: @DonSpan Done. Now the `mapply` call returns the error caught by `tryCatch`, if any, or the character string `"Ok"`. It is easy to change this if you want to.

Comment: Hi, this is working great. Now when i see complete code I even have loose understanding what is happeining. Thank you for help, really appreciate.

Comment: @DonSpan See if the explanation is helpful.